# program flow in recursive method in java

Tags: java, recursion, methods

```
class Test {

    int i=0;

    void method2() {

        if(i==6) return;
        System.out.print("before");
        i++;
        method2();
        System.out.println("after"):            
    }
}
```

If I call `method2()` from another class then I want to know how the program will flow here or why the output that's executed.

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself using a debugger?

Comment: Simple debugging would've helped you. Otherwise use print statements where ever you want and from the console you can get the flow.

Answer (score 1):

In depth knowledge of recursion can be found here
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)
As far as your program is concerned it will stop when i=6
Otherwise it will keep on printing before.
This is because in programming the flow of control is never skipped it follows the flow of control but it is not that it leaves the rest statement so whenever a new call to a function is generated the previous status of the functioning is being pushed in stack one by one and so the stack is kept on increasing and when finally the end condition is reached it pops all function calls one by one from the activation record and does the required processing is done and thus recursion works.
It takes help of a stack for doing operations.
The program flow always follows it's order wheather you call it from anywhere.
So the program flow remains same.
You will easily understand the working if you run it and add some more print statement with also the values of i.